# DNSMasq lookup dns for domain by interface

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I have DD-WRT running dns-masq to use different name servers for a wireless access point. I want to take this one step further but I can't seem to get it working. My current setup (which works perfectly)

```
dhcp-option=br1,x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y
```

Now I want to have two domains specifically, use a different name server but **only** on this interface (br1). I see that I could do this via the "server" option such as:

```
server=/domain.com/a.a.a.a
server=/domain.com/z.z.z.z
```

How can I enforce these two entries on an interface only basis?

Thanks.

Comment: After a bit more digging in the man page I got it working. The answer is a simple: 
`server=/domain.com/a.a.a.a@br1
server=/domain.com/z.z.z.z@br1`

where br1 is the interface to restrict to.